# Is there an equivalent service to Mailosaur in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to perform the following in an automated fashion

Create email addresses on the fly using API
Access email inbox using API
Read emails an it's contents using API

Is there an equivalent service to [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com/) in AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent service to Mailosaur in AWS.

There is only [Simple Email Service: Email sending and receiving service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [WorkMail: Secure email and calendaring service](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/).